# EF Ignoring Fluent Many-To-Many Configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My DbContext appears to be ignoring my fluent configurations for a specific entity. It's generating the table `SubRegionRegions` in the `OUTER JOIN`'s subquery, when I clearly have the table specified in the fluent configurations.

Sql:

```
SELECT  Project1.Id AS Id
      , Project1.Name AS Name
      , Project1.GeographyCategoryId AS GeographyCategoryId
      , Project1.C1 AS C1
      , Project1.Id1 AS Id1
      , Project1.Name1 AS Name1
      , Project1.GeographyCategoryId1 AS GeographyCategoryId1
FROM    ( SELECT    Extent1.Id AS Id
                  , Extent1.Name AS Name
                  , Extent1.GeographyCategoryId AS GeographyCategoryId
                  , Join1.Id AS Id1
                  , Join1.Name AS Name1
                  , Join1.GeographyCategoryId AS GeographyCategoryId1
                  , CASE WHEN ( Join1.SubRegion_Id IS NULL ) THEN CAST(NULL AS INT)
                         ELSE 1
                    END AS C1
          FROM      dbo.Regions AS Extent1
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT  Extent2.SubRegion_Id AS SubRegion_Id
                                  , Extent2.Region_Id AS Region_Id
                                  , Extent3.Id AS Id
                                  , Extent3.Name AS Name
                                  , Extent3.GeographyCategoryId AS GeographyCategoryId
                            FROM    dbo.SubRegionRegions AS Extent2
                            INNER JOIN dbo.SubRegions AS Extent3
                            ON      Extent3.Id = Extent2.SubRegion_Id ) AS Join1
          ON        Extent1.Id = Join1.Region_Id ) AS Project1
ORDER BY Project1.Id ASC
      , Project1.C1 ASC;
```

Fluent Configuration:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Region>()
    .HasMany(t => t.SubRegions)
    .WithMany(t => t.Regions)
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("RegionSubRegion", "dbo");
            m.MapLeftKey("RegionId");
            m.MapRightKey("SubRegionId");
        });
```

Entities:

```
[Table("SubRegions", Schema = "dbo")]
public class SubRegion
{
    public SubRegion()
    {
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column(@"Id", Order = 1, TypeName = "int")]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(@"Name", Order = 2, TypeName = "varchar")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(@"GeographyCategoryId", Order = 3, TypeName = "int")]
    [Required]
    public int GeographyCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GeographyCategoryId")]
    public virtual GeographyCategory GeographyCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Territory> Territories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeesResponsible { get; set; }
}

[Table("Regions", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Region
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column(@"Id", Order = 1, TypeName = "int")]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(@"Name", Order = 2, TypeName = "varchar")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(@"GeographyCategoryId", Order = 3, TypeName = "int")]
    [Required]
    public int GeographyCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GeographyCategoryId")]
    public virtual GeographyCategory GeographyCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubRegion> SubRegions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeesResponsible { get; set; }
}
```

Table Definitions:

```
-- SubRegions

CREATE TABLE dbo.SubRegions
    (
      Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION
    , Name VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
    , GeographyCategoryId INT NOT NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY];
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SubRegions ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SubRegions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FK_GeographyCategorySubRegion ON dbo.SubRegions (GeographyCategoryId) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SubRegions ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SubRegions_GeographyCategories FOREIGN KEY (GeographyCategoryId) REFERENCES dbo.GeographyCategories (Id);
GO


-- Regions

CREATE TABLE dbo.Regions
    (
      Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION
    , Name VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
    , GeographyCategoryId INT NOT NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY];
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Regions ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Regions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FK_GeographyCategoryRegion ON dbo.Regions (GeographyCategoryId) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Regions ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Regions_GeographyCategories FOREIGN KEY (GeographyCategoryId) REFERENCES dbo.GeographyCategories (Id);
GO

-- RegionSubRegions

CREATE TABLE dbo.RegionSubRegion
    (
      RegionId INT NOT NULL
    , SubRegionId INT NOT NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY];
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.RegionSubRegion ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SubRegionRegion PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (SubRegionId, RegionId) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FK_SubRegionRegion_Region ON dbo.RegionSubRegion (RegionId) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.RegionSubRegion ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SubRegionRegion_Region FOREIGN KEY (RegionId) REFERENCES dbo.Regions (Id);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.RegionSubRegion ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SubRegionRegion_SubRegion FOREIGN KEY (SubRegionId) REFERENCES dbo.SubRegions (Id);
GO
```

It's generating it's own based off of convention. Why is it not using the specified columns and table names in the models and configuration? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting to debug and step through my unit tests, I discovered that my unit tests were building against wrong/out-of-date reference assemblies.

Updating the references resolved the issue.

So many hours.